# R ggplot2 axis transformations broken

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm performing what I feel should be an easy transformation of my y-axis, specifically a square root transformation. I'll use the mtcars data set with the 'disp' variable.

`summary(mtcars$disp)` yields a max of 472.0.

How can the following graph, with a transformed sqrt-y-axis have any values above 21.7 which is the `sqrt(472)`? There should be no values above 21.7, yet the graph has many! It doesn't even look transformed at all.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = disp)) +
geom_point(position = position_jitter()) +
coord_trans(y = 'sqrt')
```

PS - I understand I'm missing something simple here and couldn't come up with a better title. I doubt ggplot is broken. What's going on?

Comment: You transform the coordinate system with the `coord_trans` function, this means the y-axis has a different scaling, but the values of your y-variable stay the same. Try log10 instead of sqrt and it becomes more obious. If you want to transform the data you can do this in the mapping (aes) - call

Comment: I changed the coordinate transformation to 'coord_trans(y = 'log10')'. That makes things a lot clearer and shows how the axis is transformed. :)